# Default server name nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

A server is hosting several website each having its own domain name. Nginx is used the reverse proxy.

When a domain name is pointing to the IP of the server and that no `server_name` is specified nginx serves a **default** one that matches with the first configuration file.

I want to avoid this behavior and set on my own the **default** website nginx should serve.

How can I do this? How can a _default `server_name server` be chosen when the domain name requested is non-existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `default_server` keyword to the `listen` directive.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more information.